# No funciona la redirección

Tags: php, web

Tengo este código en un archivo que he llamado **styles.php**:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["hl"]) && !empty($_GET["hl"])) {
    switch ($_GET["hl"]) {
      case 'es':
        include_once "lang/es_ES.php";
        $hl = "es";
        break;

      case 'en':
        include_once "lang/en_EN.php";
        $hl = "en";
        break;

      default:
      $url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
          header('location: '.$url.'?hl=es');
        break;
    }
  }else{
    header('location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?hl=es');
  } ?>
```

Y el siguiente código en **index.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">



  <?php include_once "includes/styles.php"; ?>

    <title><?php echo TitleHome; ?> | NoAlGluten</title>


  </head>

  <body>

<?php include_once "includes/navbar.php"; ?>

    <div class="animated zoomIn position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-light">
      <div class="col-md-5 p-lg-5 mx-auto my-5">
        <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-normal"><?php echo TITULO_1; ?></h1>
        <p class="lead font-weight-normal"><?php echo PARRAFO_PRINCIPAL; ?></p>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#"><?php echo BtnCS ?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Con esto, intento redirigir todo el tráfico que entre a [URL]?hl=es, sin embargo, el tráfico es dirigido a ?hl=, es decir, no completa con **es**. Además, como reflejo en **styles.php**, si no se utiliza el atributo GET, se redirige automáticamente a ?hl=es. Esto me funciona cuando lo pruebo localmente, sin embargo, al subirlo a mi hosting deja de funcionar y en vez de aparecer lo definido en **es_ES.php**, aparecen las variables tal y como están.

¿Alguna idea?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacer una redirección con header() después de haber tenido algún tipo de salida de texto en pantalla, por lo que el bloque de redirección debería estar colocado en la parte superior del script:

```
<?php header('location: loQueSea.php'); ?>
<html>...
```

Si cometes el error de mostrar aunque sea un caracter espacio, símbolo u otro antes de una redirección con `header()`:

```
<?php echo " "; header('location: otroLado.php') ?>
```

Recibirías un error como este:

> “Cannot modify header information”

Podrías mirar esto: https://cybmeta.com/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent

Muchas veces las versiones de apache, php, mysql, etc. son más estrictas por cuestiones de seguridad en hostings, por lo que en local muchas veces algo podría funcionar pero al hacer pruebas en servidor remoto no obtienes los resultados esperados, checa el `error_log` que pudiera estar generando.

¿Ya revisaste que estén llegando los datos a $_GET? Como sugerencia para salir del apuro, puedes analizar tus variables en todos tus posibles casos con `print_r()` o `var_dump()` y ahí revisar el porqué no funciona tu lógica.